# MediaPlayer.prepare() is giving an IOException

Tags: android

I am reading the song list from internal storage memory. I can see the song list but when I click to play it, mp.prepare throws an IOException. Please Help. Do I have to add specific permissions if I am reading from internal storage as well?-

```
public class MusicPlay extends ListActivity {
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
        "/storage/sdcard0/Music");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
private int currPos = 0;
ListView lv = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updateSongList();

}

public void updateSongList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.song_item, songs);
    setListAdapter(songList);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    currPos = position;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", 10).show();
    playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
}

private void playSong(String songPath) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.reset();
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songPath);

        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                nextSong();
            }

            private void nextSong() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (++currPos >= songs.size()) {
                    // Last song, just reset currentPosition
                    currPos = 0;
                } else {
                    // Play next song
                    playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currPos));
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would suggest not hard coding path, use this:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
            || Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        File path = manager.path = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
}
```

Code seems fine to me, i think your path is wrong. Or you haven't added priviledges to manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the seperator between the song path and name. Change MEDIA_PATH  to:

```
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
    "/storage/sdcard0/Music/");
```

Also, I'd generally recommend using File, which automatically adds missing separators when using the constructor `new File (String path, String name);`